# How to send the the values to dropdown lists whose input type is text instead of select?

Tags: python, selenium, combobox, selenium-chromedriver, dropdown

I was trying to automate the ticket creation automation for the verizon site https://myverizonenterprise.verizon.com/vec/public/quicktasks/repairs/index.html#/repairsqf/tickets/create

In this site I want to send the value to the dropdown box of state field. But, unfortunately no solution is working for me.
I tried below code in python, but that didn't work.

```
state = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='combobox-1062-trigger-picker']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'TX')]").click()
```

I have also tried following code.

```
state = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='combobox-1062-trigger-picker']")
state.send_keys('TX')
```

Even this solution didn't work for me.

Can anybody provide me a working solution?

Thanks,
Malleshappa Teli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply implicit wait or fluent wait in your code wherever it is required

**Implicit wait**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

**Explicit wait**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='TX']")))
```

**Example code:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15) # implicit wait

driver.get("https://myverizonenterprise.verizon.com/vec/public/quicktasks/repairs/index.html#/repairsqf/tickets/create");


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='state']").click()
#WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='TX']"))) #Wait for specific element 
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='TX']")).perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='TX']").click()


driver.quit()
```

Comment: I am getting error for driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='TX']").click() this line.selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Comment: @MalleshappaTeli Have you tried the above code ? if you so, can you please update your question with the full code?

Comment: Try just the code that is there in my answer and let me know if any errors

Comment: @MalleshappaTeli It works perfectly for me without any issues. I am not sure why it is not working for you. Can you please post the code that you have tried on your machine?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15) # implicit wait
driver.get("https://myverizonenterprise.verizon.com/vec/public/quicktasks/repairs/index.html#/repairsqf/tickets/create");
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='state']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='TX']"))) #Wait for specific element
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='TX']").click()
driver.quit()

Comment: I will have look and let you know

Comment: This is the script I am running, which is almost same as yours. But, still I am getting selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable for this  line   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='TX']").click()

Comment: Is it because you are using linux platform?

Comment: I am running on Mac OS chrome browser. What about you?

Comment: @MalleshappaTeli I have update my code with ActionChains. Can you please check and let me know?

Comment: I am running it in windows..I will check your code and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @MalleshappaTeli Good to Hear ! Can i get upvote as it is working after so many tries?